# Social Engine - Mobile version CSS not appearing

Tags: php, mobile, socialengine

In my social engine I am using Gordon Pro theme, it is appearing properly in Desktop/Laptops, but in mobile it is taking completely different colors.

When I checked mobile.css file, there all the background color are dynamically coming from theme's CSS.

Why the same colors are not reflecting on mobile? Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile version takes not only mobile.css, but also another (simplified) template (and blocks structure).

You should also check if the full theme.css file also uses colors which are dynamically coming to this file.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the mobile.css file in your theme folder.
In socialengine, there is a mobi module also which is responsible for the mobile rendering of the files

When you go and check the mobile.css in theme folder you can see the other css files included on top.

Also keep in mind that all mobile.css files in each and every modules are also included and minified.

Use chrome or firefox usb debugger tool for better understanding